# Fast fourier transform and nyquist frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, signal-processing, sampling

Trying to figure out how to use Matlab to calculate the nyquist frequency of a signal.

Given a function, lets say $y = 5\sin (2t + \pi /3) + \sin (t + \pi /2)$ for $t > 0$. How do we use a fft in matlab to get the nyquist frequency?

I've tried using the **fft()** function, but I'm a little confused at the results.  The optional sampling number parameter is also confusing me a bit as the sampling rate is what I'm trying to find and playing with it seems to change the results of the plot.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you do this analytically? Or do you have to use matlab? I ask because the answer for real signals is simply twice the signal's highest frequency. Thus, in your case the Nyquist rate is simply 4(Hz) (though in practice you would provide a buffer and sample at 5(Hz) or higher). I guess you *could* do it in matlab using FFTs if you knew the max possible frequency of your signal, but I don't see the appeal of this method. Basically, you would sample your signal at the max possible rate and then numerically look for signal's max frequency. Double that value and you have the Nyquist rate.

Comment: You're right, I was overthinking it.  After looking at it further I realized that I already have the fundamental frequencies right in front of me.  The highest frequency in this case is 2Hz, so 4Hz makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nyquist frequency is simply half the sampling frequency of a sampled signal. Since you didn't specify any sampling frequency, and you used $t$ as the time variable, which usually refers to continuous time, there is no way to answer your question. In general you don't need Matlab or the FFT, you just need to know (or choose) the sampling frequency, and you'll know the Nyquist rate right away.

Comment: Interesting. I never knew people drew a distinction. From the wikipedia page: "The Nyquist frequency should not be confused with the Nyquist rate, which is the minimum sampling rate that satisfies the Nyquist sampling criterion for a given signal or family of signals."

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: The distinction is indeed not always made. If you sample an analog signal at the minimum possible sampling rate (the Nyquist rate), then the Nyquist frequency of the discrete-time signal equals the Nyquist rate.